# PHP affected rows = 1 wont work properly

Tags: php, mysql

My script:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include "tilslut.php";
$userid = $_GET["userid"];
$s = mysql_query("SELECT points, lastpoint FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
$n = mysql_fetch_array($s);
$tid = time(); 
mysql_query("UPDATE member_profile set points = points+1, lastpoint=$tid  WHERE lastpoint<=$tid-60 AND user_id = '".$userid."'");
$e = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
$f = mysql_fetch_array($e); 
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
$s = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
$n = mysql_fetch_array($s);
?>
Inserted!
<?
}else{
echo "Already got";
}
ob_flush();
?>
```

I have this for giving points. 
The update query works, and only give point if lastpoint<=time()-60,  but it still say "Inserted" even though it doesnt insert.
I have tried to use mysql-affected-rows to check if it has affected or not, but this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: That include file is unfortunately named.

Comment: the include file is a db connection

Comment: @Anon. - at least it doesn't start with an 'l' instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to call mysql_affected_rows immediately after the update, before you do another select. mysql_affected_rows will only work on the last query performed on the connection.

Answer (score 3):

You are :

- doing the `update` query
- then, doing a `select` query
- and, only then, calling `mysql_affected_rows`

It might work better if you were calling `mysql_affected_rows` immediatly after the `update` query, without having another query between those : `mysql_affected_rows` is supposed to work with the data from the last query *-- even though the documentation doesn't say about `select` queries, I suppose this could cause some problem.*

As a side-note : you have some risk of SQL Injection, here : you should escape your data before injecting into an SQL query *(I'm thinking about `$_GET["userid"]`)*, or, at least, make sure it's an integer.

And you should use more descriptive variable names : `$e`, `$f`, `$n`, `$s`, ... this makes your code harder to read/understand/maintain :-(

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i already accepted the first answer, which were the same solution as you. And thanks for your note, and i know that already, but im just testing the script for now.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for your comment :-) I just though that a couple of words about escaping can never hurt :-)

Comment: "documentation doesn't say about select queries" - SELECT queries don't affect the rows in question, as SELECT is read-only. Therefore, number of rows affected by SELECT queries is 0, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Youru query

```
$e = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'");
```

is causing the affected row to equal one. I suggest you check for affected rows immediately after update

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i already accepted the first answer, which were the same solution as you.